# Android, messaging between 2 registered users advice

Tags: android, sms, messaging

I have a scenario where I register users to the system and after they are logged in then I would like to create something like a field called messages(i.e. Facebook messaging system) so 2 users can communicate between each other. This is just an idea but I am trying to find some resources and documentation on line without any luck of how can I achieve this. Can someone give me some advice please on what tools I could use in order to make this idea work ?

I am not asking for source code or so, I just need some advice on how I could achieve this or any kind of references to similar projects would be much appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

This is a perfect use case for a cloud pub/sub messaging service like Pusher or Realtime.co

Check this chat examples on github for Android and iOS:

https://github.com/realtime-framework/MessagingAndroidChat

https://github.com/realtime-framework/MessagingSwiftChat

Answer (score 0):

Note: I work for SightCall. :-)

We offer a platform for realtime communication on mobiles and browsers.  While we are best known for WebRTC Video, we also have a realtime data facility that makes it easy to send text-messages between two logged-in endpoints.

We have a sample Android App that shows how to use the framework.  You can get an API key for free for a trial.

https://github.com/sightcall/Communicator-for-Android

Of particular interest to you regarding sending/receiving text messages - notice the lines concerning the use of

```
rtcc.dataChannel().send(bytes, 0, uid);
```

This is where a text message is sent to a User named by their 'uid', and the method

```
@RtccEventListener
public void onDataChannelOutOfBandEvent(DataChannelOutOfBandEvent event)
```

This is where a text message is received as an event.